# Converting an exe recipe file to a regular exe file to run on desktop

Tags: c++, c, cmd, filesystems, exe

I want to create just a simple exe file from some code i am trying in c++
when i try to create exe file it creates a exe recipe and it does not work.
how do i fix that problem i tried looking it up and could not find a good answer.
i am just trying to create a snake game and run it as a exe file.
i am using visual studio public for school work.

[image]

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<iostream>

bool gameover;
const int height = 15;
const int width = 80;
int x, y, fruitX, fruitY, score=0;
enum eDirection { STOP = 0, UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT };
eDirection dir;
int tailx[100], taily[100], ctail = 0;


void setup()
{
    gameover = false;
    
    x = width / 2;
    y = height / 2;
    srand(time(0));
    fruitX = rand() % width + 1;
    fruitY = rand() % height;
}

void board()
{

    system("CLS");
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        
        printf("#");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            if (j == 0 || j == width - 1)
                printf("#");
            else
            {
                if (i == fruitY && j == fruitX)
                    printf("f");
                else
                    if (i == y && j == x)
                        printf("o");
                    else
                    {
                        
                        bool print = false;
                        for (int k = 0; k < ctail; k++)
                        {

                            if (i == taily[k] && j == tailx[k])
                            {
                                printf("o");
                                print = true;
                            }
                        }
                        if (!print)
                            printf(" ");
                    }
            }

        }


    }
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {

        printf("#");
    }
    printf("\n x is %d y is %d", fruitX, fruitY);
    printf("\n\n the score is %d\n\n",score);






}
void input()
{
    if(_kbhit())
        switch (_getch())
        {
        case 'w':dir = UP;
            break;
        case 's':dir = DOWN;
            break;
        case 'a':dir = LEFT;
            break;
        case 'd':dir = RIGHT;
            break;
        default:break;
        }
}
void logic()
{
    int prevx = tailx[0];
    int prevy = taily[0];
    tailx[0] = x;
    taily[0] = y;
    int prev2x, prev2y;
    for (int i = 1; i < ctail; i++)
    {
        prev2x = tailx[i];
        prev2y = taily[i];
        tailx[i] = prevx;
        taily[i] = prevy;
        prevx = prev2x;
        prevy = prev2y;
        
    }


    switch (dir)
    {
    case UP:y--;
        break;
    case DOWN:y++;
        break;
    case LEFT:x--;
        break;
    case RIGHT:x++;
        break;
    default:break;
    }
    if (x<0 || x>width )
        gameover = true;
    if (y<0-1 || y>height)
        gameover = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < ctail; i++)
    {
        if (x == tailx[i] && y == taily[i])
            gameover = true;
    }

    if (x == fruitX && y == fruitY)
    {
        score += 10;
        fruitX = rand() % (width-1) + 1;
        fruitY = rand() % height;
        ctail++;
    }
}

int main()
{

    setup();
    while (!gameover)
    {
        board();
        input();
        logic();
        Sleep(5);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What "doesn't work"? What does that mean? If you don't want this file, you can ignore it (though my VS doesn't create those, weird).

Comment: The file above the "recipe" file is probably the exe. You seem to have the _"Hide extension for known file types"_ checked in your file explorer settings.

Comment: The comment above is clearly the answer. Always start with a "Hello world" program is a good piece of advice however.

Comment: OP needs to go backwards in the File Explorer. The EXE is going to be at `source\repos\gfgfgfgfdgdfgdfgdfgdfg\Debug`. See the answer posted below.

Answer (score 1):

A picture says a thousand words!

Well... here are some pictures! Maybe this will help :)

[image: File Directory]

[image: Play the Game]

Comment: Not in OP's case, apparently. You can see the executable on their screenshot, they just have the extension hidden.

Comment: I looked at the screenshot again. Yep, it is right there in his folder... in plain sight.

Answer (score 0):

This file isn't executable. If you want to run your executable go to the location which includes the executable file. These files are in the intermediate directory, but the executable file always places in a directory which is called the output directory. These settings can be watched in the project properties of your visual studio. Output directory as the default set to the $(SolutionDir)$(Platform)$(Configuration). However, Once the project is built, navigate to the folder where the executable file is located. By default, the executable file is created in the project's "Debug" or "Release" folder, depending on the build configuration.